# Replace some part of string with image component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, emoji

Hi friends I have in my database saved text strings that contain emoji codes, this is an example text string is as follows:

:kiss_mm::kiss_mm::kiss_mm:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.:couple_mm: Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,:star::star: when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.:telephone::telephone:

I call a function to make a replacement of emoji codes with images

```
  <View>
    <Text style={{ minHeight: 50 }}>{this.replaceEmoticons(item.posttexto)}</Text>
 </View>
```

and my JS functions are:

```
RegExpEscape = (text) => {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
replaceEmoticons = (text) => {

    let emoticons = {
            ":kiss_mm:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/1f468-2764-1f48b-1f468.png",
        ":kiss_woman_man:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/1f469-2764-1f48b-1f468.png",
        ":kiss_ww:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/1f469-2764-1f48b-1f469.png",
        ":england:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/1f3f4-e0067-e0062-e0065-e006e-e0067-e007f.png",
        ":scotland:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/1f3f4-e0067-e0062-e0073-e0063-e0074-e007f.png",
        ":wales:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/1f3f4-e0067-e0062-e0077-e006c-e0073-e007f.png",
        ":family_mmbb:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/1f468-1f468-1f466-1f466.png",
        ":family_mmgb:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/1f468-1f468-1f467-1f466.png",
        ":wavy_dash:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/3030.png",
        ":wheel_of_dharma:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/2638.png",
        ":wheelchair:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/267f.png",
        ":white_check_mark:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/2705.png",
        ":white_circle:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/26aa.png",
        ":white_large_square:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/2b1c.png",
        ":white_medium_small_square:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/25fd.png",
        ":white_medium_square:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/25fb.png",
        ":white_small_square:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/25ab.png",
        ":writing_hand:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/270d.png",
        ":x:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/274c.png",
        ":yin_yang:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/262f.png",
        ":zap:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/26a1.png",
        ":sparkles:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/2728.png",
        ":star:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/2b50.png",
        ":star_and_crescent:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/262a.png",
        ":star_of_david:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/2721.png",
        ":stop_button:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/23f9.png",
        ":stopwatch:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/23f1.png",
        ":sunny:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/2600.png",
        ":taurus:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/2649.png",
        ":telephone:": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/v31/png/32/260e.png",
          ..........
          ..........
    }

    let result = text;
    let emotcode;
    let regex;

    for (emotcode in emoticons) {
        regex = new RegExp(this.RegExpEscape(emotcode), 'gi');
        result = result.replace(regex, function (match) {
            var pic = emoticons[match];
            if (pic != undefined) {
                return (
                <Image style={styles.emtotic} source={{uri: pic}} />
                )

            } else {
                return match;
            }
        });
    }
    return result;


}
```

The function searches for each Emoji code in my text string and the one it finds replaces it with its respective image but returns me with an [Object Object], if I put the:

```
                return (
                "<Image style={styles.emtotic} source={{uri:"+ pic +"}} />"
                )
```

It returns the characters in the form of Srings and does not show the image.
  Any suggestions on how I can replace the characters? Let the function find all the emoji codes in my text string and replace it with its respective image, thank you very much

Comment: Thats because you're putting it in a string. Dont do that, you need to render the content.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a `split` on the text by emoticons. Then replace the split string array into an array of elements based off of that string. Heres an example.

```
function ParsedText({ text }) {
  return text.split(/(:.*?:)/g).map(elem => {
    if (!elem) return null;
    if (emoticons[elem]) {
      return <Image style={styles.emtotic} source={{uri: emoticons[elem]}} />;
    }
    return <Text>{elem}</Text>;
  });
}
```

Where usage of this would be something like

```
<ParsedText text={theTextToEmoticonify} />
```

[**Heres a (React not React-Native) live example to play with**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-icgkq). The concepts are there for you to port to your application :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, if it worked, I have a little doubt..

Comment: Why does it load very slowly and sometimes the application hangs when I post more than 150 icons? Is it due to function problems?, many requests at the same time?

Comment: It's probably all of the requests. Maybe download the assets or limit the number of emojis